# How to reshape data frame in R or Excel?

Tags: r, excel

Here's the code to get a sample data set:

```
set.seed(0)
practice <- matrix(sample(1:100, 20), ncol = 2)
data <- as.data.frame(practice)
data <- cbind( lob = sprintf("objective%d", rep(1:2,each=5)), data)
data <- cbind( student = sprintf("student%d", rep(1:5,2)), data)
names(data) <- c("student", "learning objective","attempt", "score")
data[-8,]
```

The data looks like this:

```
    student learning objective attempt score
1  student1         objective1      90     6
2  student2         objective1      27    19
3  student3         objective1      37    16
4  student4         objective1      56    60
5  student5         objective1      88    34
6  student1         objective2      20    66
7  student2         objective2      85    42
9  student4         objective2      61    82
10 student5         objective2      58    31
```

What I want is:

```
    student       objective1         objective2 
                 attempt  score     attempt score
1  student1         90     6          20      66
2  student2         27    19          85      42
3  student3         ...                0       0
4  student4         ...                  ...
5  student5         ...                  ...
```

There are 70 learning objectives, so it's going to be tedious to just copy and paste the attempts and scores, so I wonder whether there's a better way to clean the data.

**R:** I was trying to use the `melt` function in R to get the new data, but it doesn't work well. There are missing scores for some of the students and the student name is not listed, for example `student3` in this case, so I cannot just `cbind` the score.

**Excel:** There are 70 learning objectives, and because of missing names, I have to check all corresponding rows for all those 70 objectives for `VLOOKUP`:

```
(=VLOOKUP($C7,'0learning.csv'!$B$372:$G$395,5,0)
(=VLOOKUP($C7,'0learning.csv'!$B$372:$G$395,6,0)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use the devel version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5` which can take take multiple `value.var` columns and reshape the 'long' form to 'wide'.  Instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 names(data)[2] <- 'objective'
 dcast(setDT(data), student~objective, value.var=c('attempt', 'score'))
 #    student attempt_objective1 attempt_objective2 score_objective1
 #1: student1                 90                 20                6
 #2: student2                 27                 85               19
 #3: student3                 37                 96               16
 #4: student4                 56                 61               60
 #5: student5                 88                 58               34
 #    score_objective2
 #1:               66
 #2:               42
 #3:               87
 #4:               82
 #5:               31
```

Or using `reshape` from `base R`

```
 reshape(data, idvar='student', timevar='objective', direction='wide')
 #  student attempt.objective1 score.objective1 attempt.objective2
 #  1 student1                 90                6                 20
 #  2 student2                 27               19                 85
 #  3 student3                 37               16                 96
 #  4 student4                 56               60                 61
 #  5 student5                 88               34                 58
 #    score.objective2
 #  1               66
 #  2               42
 #  3               87
 #  4               82
 #  5               31
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems there are errors for both of the two lines of codes.. 1:> names(data)[2] <- 'objective'
Warning message:...2:> dcast(setDT(data), student~objective, value.var=c('attempt', 'score'))
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @SongTianyang  Are you using the devel version of `data.table`?

Comment: @SongTianyang  I added a `base R` version, it should work if you dont have the devel version of data.table

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded the package, but the default version is 1.9.4.

Comment: The reshape one works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @SongTianyang  In the CRAN, it is 1.9.4.  If you look at the link I mentioned in the post, it gives you access to download and install the devel versin